# Execution of ADODB statements stop suddenly

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, adodb

Good morning, 
I have an application already done, and it was working fine until I add a new field to one of the tables.
I'm required to save Files on the DB, because they don't want to have a location to save the files and also they will need to create a backup system to save those files once they are uploaded.

I'm saving the files on the DB, 
On SQL I have the data type as VarBinary

the function in ADODB that retrieve the information was good, but when i add the lines to get the filecontent, im debugging and everytime the application reach that line of code the execution just stop. WEIRD for me, no error no event viewer error, no compilation error just stop.

```
 if (sqlDataReader["filetable"] != null && sqlDataReader["filetable"].ToString().Length > 0)
                    {
                        item.FileTable = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sqlDataReader["filetable"].ToString());
                    }
```

this is the line of code that is stopping execution

when the debugger is inside the if, it just stop debugging the application.

any idea with this I will appreciate.
this is driving me crazy.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Have you tried putting a try catch around that 1 line and see if there's an exception being thrown?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have tried the try catch and nothing, no exceptions on the code.

Comment: @Wheels73 yes i have the try catch!! and nothing.

Comment: I don't think the statement `sqlDataReader["filetable"].ToString()` will do what you want it to do. That statement will return `System.Byte[]`

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to check to ensure the field is not DBNull. Checking for null is not the same thing as it not the same thing as null in a database.

```
sqlDataReader["filetable"] != DBNull.value
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I was checking that before, and nothing.